# Why is "requests" in Python unable to download this url image but the browser can?

Tags: python, http, browser, python-requests

I have the following url that is actually an image.

```
https://cache.mrporter.com/images/products/908290/908290_mrp_in_l.jpg
```

I am using the below Python code to download it

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import requests
response = requests.get("https://cache.mrporter.com/images/products/908290/908290_mrp_in_l.jpg")
```

I see that the requests.get just hangs and if I use a timeout of even 5 seconds I get the TimeOut Exception.

However, when I paste the url in the browser, I immediately see it open.

I am really stuck here and trying to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the website needs an `User-Agent`. You could try with the following

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get("https://cache.mrporter.com/images/products/908290/908290_mrp_in_l.jpg", headers=headers)
```

This returns `<Response [200]>`

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: I can accept in 6 mins according to Stackoverflow :)